# Show statistics (average, StdDev, Min/Max) for visible data with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want the user to be able to dynamically analyse data in a given plotly html export/plot.
Based on the values currently shown in the plot I want to display some statistics on the data like average, StdDev, Min/Max.

Using this code I can generate a plot showing a sine wave.
Now I want to dynamically adjust the "title" (or another annotation) to show the statistics for the currently shown data.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Generate some sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

# Calculate the statistics
avg = np.mean(y)
min_val = np.min(y)
max_val = np.max(y)

# Create the plot
fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y),
    layout=go.Layout(
        title=f'Sine Waveform\nAverage: {avg:.2f}, Min: {min_val:.2f}, Max: {max_val:.2f}',
        xaxis=dict(title='x'),
        yaxis=dict(title='y')
    )
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

A solution using `plotly-dash` would also be fine.

Comment: when you say values currently shown in the plot, you mean when the user zooms in or out? if so, this will require use of `callbacks` which is available in `plotly-dash`, but not plotly. i can write out a dash based solution if you're interested though

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. plotly-dash sounds great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plotly-dash` which supports [callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks). We can create a callback function that takes the layout data of the figure as an input, modify the title of the figure, and output the figure to the app in real time when the user zooms (there's also an edge case where we reset the figure and its title when the user refreshes the page).

Below is a working code sample:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

app = Dash(__name__)

# Generate some sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

# Calculate the statistics
avg = np.mean(y)
min_val = np.min(y)
max_val = np.max(y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

# Create the plot
fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y),
    layout=go.Layout(
        title=f'Sine Waveform\nAverage: {avg:.2f}, Min: {min_val:.2f}, Max: {max_val:.2f}',
        xaxis=dict(title='x'),
        yaxis=dict(title='y')
    )
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id='scatter-chart')]
)

@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-chart', 'figure'),
    Input('scatter-chart', 'relayoutData'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_title(relayout_data):
    try:
        x_min, x_max = relayout_data['xaxis.range[0]'], relayout_data['xaxis.range[1]']
        y_min, y_max = relayout_data['yaxis.range[0]'], relayout_data['yaxis.range[1]']
    except:
        avg = np.mean(y)
        min_val = np.min(y)
        max_val = np.max(y)
        y_pad = (max_val-min_val)/16

        fig.update_layout(
            xaxis_range=[min(x), max(x)],
            yaxis_range=[min(y)-y_pad, max(y)+y_pad],
            title=f'Sine Waveform\nAverage: {avg:.2f}, Min: {min_val:.2f}, Max: {max_val:.2f}'
        )
        return fig

    df_subset = df[
        df['x'].between(x_min,x_max) & 
        df['y'].between(y_min,y_max)
    ]

    avg = df_subset['y'].mean()
    min_val, max_val = df_subset['y'].min(), df_subset['y'].max()

    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis_range=[x_min, x_max],
        yaxis_range=[y_min, y_max],
        title=f'Sine Waveform\nAverage: {avg:.2f}, Min: {min_val:.2f}, Max: {max_val:.2f}'
    )

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]