# Show statistics (average, std) for data selected using box/lasso select with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, event-handling, handler

I want to show statistics (average, std) for data selected using box/lasso select with Plotly.

I am trying to figure it out based on the two following examples, but I am afraid I do not understand Plotly enough to make it work. Is there an example somewhere that could help me? Thanks!

[Show statistics (average, StdDev, Min/Max) for visible data with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158826/show-statistics-average-stddev-min-max-for-visible-data-with-plotly)

https://community.plotly.com/t/handler-passed-to-on-selection-not-getting-triggered/35648