# Adding data to a table using visible data with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, event-handling, visualization, data-analysis

**Context:** I want to identify average values of several plateaus in a dataset (timeseries of gas concentrations). I am using Plotly.

**What I want to do:** I want to select data in an interactive graph using either box/lasso select or the zoom tools and calculate some statistics about the selection (average, std). Then, I want to add the calculated statistics to a dataframe or array to be able to export it.

**What I did so far:** I was able to get the statistic I want using the zoom tools. I got there by adapting the code in the following post: [Show statistics (average, StdDev, Min/Max) for visible data with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158826/show-statistics-average-stddev-min-max-for-visible-data-with-plotly)

**What I need:** I need to add a button I can click to add the statistics to a dataframe or array of table. I also need to add an export button. I would like to see the statistics that are added, like the data in this example: https://plotly.com/python/v3/selection-events/. Any advice would help!

Here's my code so far (with fake data to run it):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go

app = Dash(__name__)

# Test
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'DATE_TIME':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                          'CO2':[400,400,400,425,430,430,430,440,441,442,442,460,465,465,464,467,425,400,400,400],
                          'CH4':[2,2,2,1.9,1.8,1.85,1.85,1.7,1.69,1.68,1.65,1.4,1.41,1.41,1.42,1.41,1.7,2,2,2]})

# Data
x = data["DATE_TIME"] 
y = data["CO2"] 
y2 = data["CH4"]

# Calculate the statistics
avg = np.mean(y) 
std = np.std(y) 
std_percent = std/avg*100 
min_val = np.min(y) 
max_val = np.max(y) 
avg_CH4 = np.mean(y2) 
std_CH4 = np.std(y2) 
std_percent_CH4 = std_CH4/avg_CH4*100 
min_val_CH4 = np.min(y2) 
max_val_CH4 = np.max(y2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'y2':y2})

# Create the plot
fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines+markers'),
    layout=go.Layout(
        title=f"\nAverage CO2: <span style='color:blue'>{avg:.2f}</span> ppm, STD CO2: <span style='color:red'>{std_percent:.2f}</span> %, \nAverage CH4: <span style='color:blue'>{avg_CH4:.3f}</span> ppm, STD CH4: <span style='color:red'>{std_percent_CH4:.2f}</span> %",
        xaxis=dict(title=' '),
        yaxis=dict(title='CO2 (ppm)')
    )
)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=4))

app.layout = html.Div(
    [dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id='scatter-chart')]
)

@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-chart', 'figure'),
    Input('scatter-chart', 'relayoutData'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_title(relayout_data):
    try:
        x_min, x_max = relayout_data['xaxis.range[0]'], relayout_data['xaxis.range[1]']
        y_min, y_max = relayout_data['yaxis.range[0]'], relayout_data['yaxis.range[1]']
    except:
        avg = np.mean(y)
        std = np.std(y) 
        std_percent = std/avg*100 
        min_val = np.min(y)
        max_val = np.max(y)
        y_pad = (max_val-min_val)/16
        avg_CH4 = np.mean(y2) 
        std_CH4 = np.std(y2) 
        std_percent_CH4 = std_CH4/avg_CH4*100 
        min_val_CH4 = np.min(y2) 
        max_val_CH4 = np.max(y2)

        fig.update_layout(
            xaxis_range=[min(x), max(x)],
            yaxis_range=[min(y)-y_pad, max(y)+y_pad],
            title=f"\nAverage CO2: <span style='color:blue'>{avg:.2f}</span> ppm, STD CO2: <span style='color:red'>{std_percent:.2f}</span> %, \nAverage CH4: <span style='color:blue'>{avg_CH4:.3f}</span> ppm, STD CH4: <span style='color:red'>{std_percent_CH4:.2f}</span> %"
        )
        return fig

    df_subset = df[
        df['x'].between(x_min,x_max) & 
        df['y'].between(y_min,y_max)
    ]

    avg = df_subset['y'].mean()
    min_val, max_val = df_subset['y'].min(), df_subset['y'].max()
    std = df_subset['y'].std()
    std_percent = std/avg*100
    avg_CH4 = df_subset['y2'].mean()
    std_CH4 = df_subset['y2'].std()
    std_percent_CH4 = std_CH4/avg_CH4*100
    min_val_CH4, max_val_CH4 = df_subset['y2'].min(), df_subset['y2'].max()

    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis_range=[x_min, x_max],
        yaxis_range=[y_min, y_max],
        title=f"\nAverage CO2: <span style='color:blue'>{avg:.2f}</span> ppm, STD CO2: <span style='color:red'>{std_percent:.2f}</span> %, \nAverage CH4: <span style='color:blue'>{avg_CH4:.3f}</span> ppm, STD CH4: <span style='color:red'>{std_percent_CH4:.2f}</span> %"
    )

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```